# HTML Canvas transparent stroke line

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to clear a stroked rectangle in certain canvas area. My initial thought was that I just need to call `context.strokeRect` function again with same parameters, with changing `strokeStyle` to `transparent` before. However it isn't working. Why and how can I fix it? Note that I want to only clear stroke (border) of rectangle, not everything inside.

Edit: I want to clear only border, not everything inside, so I can't use `clearRect()` method. Also I can't clear whole canvas and repaint it, because canvas contains animations.

JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/47okok8s/

Comment: note: rgba -> (red, blue, green, alpha), the alpha value (ranging from [0,1]) controls the opacity, 1, being fully opaque [W3 CSS3 Colors](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_colors.asp)

Comment: use clearRect to clear the existing rectangle

Comment: I don't suppose [this](https://jsfiddle.net/2gLj52u4/) would work. :P  In all seriousness though, I don't think this is possible.  You would probably have better luck recording the "painting" process and replaying it but excluding the red outline step.  Canvas is a lot like painting.  You can't just undo that stroke.

Comment: Set `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out"` and all pixels rendered will have the alpha removed or reduced by the alpha of the source pixels. `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over"` restores the default

Comment: Oh the destination pixels RGB values will not be changed by the source RGB (unless the alpha result is zero in which case all channels are set to zero)

Answer (score 1):

Example below has two canvas. The `background` just has some text. Then I fill the `foreground` canvas with "red" and use `globalCompositeOperation` `"destination-out"` to remove pixels. I also set alpha to 0.5 and half remove some pixels.

```js
const ctxB = background.getContext("2d");
const ctxF = foreground.getContext("2d");
ctxB.textAlign = "center";
ctxB.textBaseline = "middle";
ctxB.font ="20px arial";
ctxB.fillText("Some Background text",150,25);
ctxB.fillText("Some Background text",150,75);
ctxB.fillText("Some Background text",150,125);

ctxF.lineJoin = "round";
ctxF.fillStyle = "red";
ctxF.fillRect(0,0,300,150);
ctxF.lineWidth = 8;
ctxF.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
ctxF.strokeRect(25,25,250,100);
ctxF.fillRect(75,50,150,50);
ctxF.globalAlpha = 0.5;
ctxF.fillRect(65,40,170,70);
ctxF.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
```

```css
canvas {
   position : absolute;
   top : 0px;
   left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id = "background"></canvas>
<canvas id = "foreground"></canvas>
```